Upgrade issue to Springboot 3.2.2
I am upgrading to spring boot 3.2.2 and Java 17. However in my application, we are using Approval Store , AuthorizationCodeService and JdbcClientDetailsServicewhich are now deprecated in Spring Security 6, which is used in Spring Boot 3.x.
From what I found is ,for modern OAuth2 workflows, we should try using the OAuth2AuthorizationService,OAuth2AuthorizationConsentService and RegisteredClientRepository interfaces for managing authorizations and approvals. But I am not sure of the implementation of the same. Here is a sample i tried, is this the correct replacement of mentioned APIs?
@Bean
public OAuth2AuthorizationService  authorizationService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate,  RegisteredClientRepository clientRepository) {
    return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(jdbcTemplate, clientRepository);
}

@Bean
public OAuth2AuthorizationConsentService authorizationConsentService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, RegisteredClientRepository clientRepository) {
    return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationConsentService(jdbcTemplate, clientRepository);
}

@Bean
@Primary
public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    JdbcRegisteredClientRepository clientRepository = new JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcTemplate);
    // Use password encoder for encoding secrets (if needed)
    return clientRepository;
}

